# Width of select is reduce by 2px after setting width using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have gone through several pages to set width of textbox and select. I used jQuery 2.0 to set this width.

**My Code snippet from my project:**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
       
           $("#Text2").css('width','200px');       
$("#uxSeries").css('width','200px');
                  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="Text2" type="text" /> <br/>
       <select id="uxSeries" />
```

This is just a small part of my project. Please see the below screen shot, for text box it sets width properly (ie. 200px) but for select it shows 198px. I don't understand why width is reduce by 2px.

[image]

Am I missing something?
Can anyone guide me on this?

Comment: Please create a [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you are making a big mistake. It is `function` and not `fuction`:

```
$(document).ready(fuction(){
//------------------^
```

Change it to:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
```

Also you can make use of the shorthand function:

```
$(function () {
```

**Snippet**

This demonstrates the issue.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#Text2").css('width','200px');       
  $("#uxSeries").css('width','200px');
});
```

```css
* {box-sizing: border-box;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="Text2" type="text" />
<select id="uxSeries"></select>
```

Comment: Sorry it's typo mistake, In my actual code it is function and the screen shot that I attached is from my actual code.

Comment: @Manish So the question you have given is wrong and you expect a right answer, that too after half an hour! Wow! OKay, correct the question and ping.

Comment: Am I asked a wrong question, I was asking to set width for both input & select which ideally done by .css property of jQuery. Can you please let me know where is my mistake.

Comment: Did you see my answer? See the CSS part.

Answer (score 0):

The provided CSS works for me

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#Text2").css('width','200px');       
  $("#uxSeries").css('width','200px');
});
```

```css
* {box-sizing: border-box;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="Text2" type="text" />
<select id="uxSeries"></select>
```